# How to add text legends in bars of a bar chart in D3?

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to add Text/Label to my bars in a bar chart using D3.Js.
My texts are appending but from the second index data first index is skipped I dont know why it is doing like this .I have debugged the dat ,data is coming correctly..
I have been doing as below:

```
function revenueBar(localDataJson) {
        var w = 400;
        var h = 400;
        var barPadding = 1;
        var maxRevenue = 0;
        var maxTurnOver = 0;
        var padding = {
            left: 45, right: 10,
            top: 40, bottom: 60
        }

        var maxWidth = w - padding.left - padding.right;
        var maxHeight = h - padding.top - padding.bottom;
        for (var j = 0; j < localDataJson.length; j++) {
            if (localDataJson[j].Revenue > maxRevenue) {
                maxRevenue = localDataJson[j].Revenue;
            }

        }
        for (var j = 0; j < localDataJson.length; j++) {
            if (localDataJson[j].TurnOver > maxTurnOver) {
                maxTurnOver = localDataJson[j].TurnOver;
            }

        }
        var convert = {
            x: d3.scale.ordinal(),
            y: d3.scale.linear()
        };
        // Define your axis
        var axis = {
            x: d3.svg.axis().orient('bottom')
            //y: d3.svg.axis().orient('left')
        };

        // Define the conversion function for the axis points
        axis.x.scale(convert.x);
       // axis.y.scale(convert.y);

        // Define the output range of your conversion functions
        convert.y.range([maxHeight, 0]);
        convert.x.rangeRoundBands([0, maxWidth]);

        convert.x.domain(localDataJson.map(function (d) {
            return d.Country;
        })
        );
        convert.y.domain([0, maxRevenue]);
        $('#chartBar').html("");
        var svg = d3.select("#chartBar")
                   .append("svg")
                   .attr("width", w)
                   .attr("height", h);
        // The group node that will contain all the other nodes
        // that render your chart
        $('.bar-group').html("");
        var chart = svg.append('g')
                             .attr({
                                 class: 'container',
                                 transform: function (d, i) {
                                     return 'translate(' + padding.left + ',' + padding.top + ')';
                                 }
                             });

        chart.append('g') // Container for the axis
                    .attr({
                        class: 'x axis',
                        transform: 'translate(0,' + maxHeight + ')'
                    })
                   .call(axis.x)
                    .selectAll("text")
                                 .attr("x", "-.8em")
                                 .attr("y", ".15em")
                         .style("text-anchor", "end")
                                .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");// Insert an axis inside this node
        $('.axis path').css("fill", "none");
        chart.append('g') // Container for the axis
           // .attr({
           //     class: 'y axis',
           //     height: maxHeight,

           // })
           //.call(axis.y);

        var bars = chart
             .selectAll('g.bar-group')
             .data(localDataJson)
             .enter()
             .append('g') // Container for the each bar
             .attr({
                 transform: function (d, i) {
                     return 'translate(' + convert.x(d.Country) + ', 1)';
                 },
                 class: 'bar-group'
             });

        var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
                      .range(['#f1595f', '#79c36a', '#599ad3', '#f9a65a', '#9e66ab','#cd7058']);
        bars.append('rect')
                    .attr({
                        y: maxHeight,
                        height: 0,
                        width: function (d) { return convert.x.rangeBand(d) - 3; },
                        class: 'bar'
                    })
                    .transition()
                    .duration(1500)
                    .attr({
                        y: function (d, i) {
                            return convert.y(d.Revenue);
                        },
                        height: function (d, i) {
                            return maxHeight - convert.y(d.Revenue);
                        }
                    })
                    .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
                        return color(i);
                    })




        var svgs = svg.selectAll("g.container")
      //  svgs.selectAll("text")
          .data(localDataJson)

          .enter()
          .append("text")
            //.transition()        // <-- This is new,
          // .duration(5000)
          .text(function (d) {
              return (d.Revenue);
          })
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          //// Set x position to the left edge of each bar plus half the bar width
          .attr("x", function (d, i) {
              return (i * (w / localDataJson.length)) + ((w / localDataJson.length - barPadding) / 2);
          })
         .attr({
             y: function (d, i) {
                 return convert.y(d.Revenue) +70;
             },
             height: function (d, i) {
                 return maxHeight - convert.y(d.Revenue);
             }
         })
       .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .attr("font-size", "13px")
        .attr("fill", "white")


    }
```

My Data is:

```
localdatajson=[
               {"Country";"USA","Revenue":"12","TurnOver":"16"},
               {"Country";"Brazil","Revenue":"4.5","TurnOver":"16"},
               {"Country";"Belzium","Revenue":"4.8","TurnOver":"16"},
               {"Country";"Britain","Revenue":"20","TurnOver":"16"},
               {"Country";"Canada","Revenue":"6.5","TurnOver":"16"},
               {"Country";"DenMark","Revenue":"7.5","TurnOver":"16"}
             ]
```

The problem is text is appending but after first one i.e., it is escaping Revenue 12.and appending from second one "4.5"

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is text is appending but after first one i.e., it is
>   escaping Revenue 12.and appending from second one "4.5"

This is because your current block that adds the `text` elements has

```
var svgs = svg.selectAll("g.container")
              .data(localDataJson)
              .enter()
              ...
```

which means that it searches for `g.container` elements within svg and tries to link each one to corresponding `localDataJson` elements (adding new ones for extra `localDataJson` elements for which it can't find a corresoponding `g.container` element).

Since you have exactly one `g.container` element, it will link the first element to that and then adds new `text` elements for the remaining.

---

You want to be doing this

```
var svgs = svg.select("g.container").selectAll("text.label")
              .data(localDataJson)
              .enter()
              .append("text")
              .classed("label", true)
              ...
```

instead i.e. match text elements in `g.container` to the data array and add a new one for each extra one.

Notice that we use `.label` and added the class `label` - this is because we want to match it to the text elements for the data labels (not say, the ones we add for the x axis labels)

---

While this solves the problem, you'll probably need a few more corrections in your x and y coordinates for the labels and you don't actually need to set a width for the labels

```
...
.attr("x", function (d, i) {
    return convert.x(d.Country) + (convert.x.rangeBand(d) - 3) / 2;
})
.attr("y", function (d, i) {
        return maxHeight;
})
...
```

I set it to maxHeight just to show it works - the bar height actually goes offchart because there's something wrong with your y scale.

Comment: Thank you so much this solves my problem :-).....Also my x attribute calculation was wrong,the x attr given by u works .Thanks

Comment: @Garima - your bar y scaling too seems to be off btw (it goes off chart for me) - you might want to check that out too. Cheers!